# Chrome extension's chrome.history not synced across devices?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-history

Trying to write a chrome extension using the chrome.history api. I'm seeing the history reported by chrome.history doesn't contain links visited on other devices (although those links do appear in the chrome://history page on the same device).

Is there an alternative to chrome.history I could use? Is there something else than an extension I could build that could access the full cross device history?

Or is there a reason for the discrepancy between chrome://history and chrome.history?

My end goal would be to highlight links that have been visited cross devices on current pages.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1072226/668411) on Super User which

> - Reset Sync by going to the Google Dashboard.
> - Log out of Chrome on all your devices (PC, Mac, smartphone, etc)
> - Quit Chrome (kill Chrome process if necessary)
> - Run Chrome again and you should be asked to sign in to your account.
> - Once all accounts are signed in, the history should sync across all devices

This will re-sync all your devices.

By the way, extensions usually are synced to all devices if users enable the feature, and this means that your app will still show the visited links since it will have access to the device it's installed on's history.

As for the synced data, not event the Chrome browser itself can highlight the data as visited. Google.com usually highlights visited sites, but I just checked my history and the sites I visited on other sites aren't showing.

To solve your issue, you can have users create Premium accounts that gives them access to cross browser link marking. This of course has to be implemented by you.

Comment: Thanks for the response!
Unfortunately, I already tried this with no success. It did help though, as before doing this the chrome://history wasn't syncing at all across devices. It is now, however, contrary to the chrome://history page, the chrome.history api still doesn't  show the synced results.
I might try to use synced storage for the extension and just create my own custom history there. It's not super elegant, but that could do the trick.

Comment: Don't use synced storage. You will have to stay within the limit set for synced data. Which is bad. Unless you are ok with only storing information for a set amount of time. So like 3 months and the data gets deleted. So if you added a history string like so "https://google.com||<date>" you can check every now and then to make sure that old entries are purged.